# Facebook login works on localhost, but not on a web server - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-login

So, I tried Facebook login with Codeigniter on localhost and everything was Ok - When I pressed login button, it showed my profile picture and logout button.

Then I uploaded script on webhost. I'm pressing login button and expect to see my profile picture, but nothing! Except for one thing, website ir, for example, on www.example.com. I press login and address bar shows www.example.com/index.php?code=AQCTt5KzYV8TKKqU5nUUuy0d5DhQLJdFOlDgJ... etc.

There's my welcome.php controller's code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Prakse extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    // To use site_url and redirect on this controller.
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

public function login() {

    $this->load->library('facebook');

    $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
        try {
            $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            $user = null;
        }
    }else {
        $this->facebook->destroySession();
    }

    if ($user) {

        $data['logout_url'] = site_url('welcome/logout'); // Logs off application
        // OR 
        // Logs off FB!
        // $data['logout_url'] = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl();

    } else {
        $data['login_url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'redirect_uri' => site_url('welcome/login'), 
            'scope' => array("email") // permissions here
        ));
    }
    $this->load->view('login',$data);

}

public function logout() {

    $this->load->library('facebook');

    // Logs off session from website
    $this->facebook->destroySession();
    // Make sure you destory website session as well.

    redirect('welcome/login');
}
```

}

Help me please. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the codeigniter config for the facebook? Is your facebook api key locked to a particular domain?

Comment: Yes and yes. Everything's double checked. All App config is right, APi-Key and Secret thing  are right...

Comment: Anything else setup to reference localhost?

Comment: @user3362165 I'm having the same problem on localhost and it's really annoying. I asked a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916954/having-an-issue-with-catch-facebookapiexception-e-in-login-with-facebook-usin but no help whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Check [https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[your_app_id]/settings/](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/%5byour_app_id%5d/settings/) and make sure app domains and site url are set correctly.