# Having an issue with catch (FacebookApiException $e) in login with facebook using php sdk

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

My facebook login code using php sdk isn't working. When I click on the login button in index.php, it opens a pop up where i enter my email and password and then it just brings me back to index.php with some **code** appended to the url like this:

```
http://localhost/test.php?code=AQAr4gedKEz01BGIGpIB5Ijh66bk9j7qhW9...etc
```

Also **$user** was returning **0** even after trying to login. I did some digging in base_facebook.php and found this. There is a function that gets an **Access Token** using the **code** from the url. It's on line 752 of base_facebook.php. That function is like this:

```
protected function getAccessTokenFromCode($code, $redirect_uri = null) {
    .
    .
    .
    try {
      // need to circumvent json_decode by calling _oauthRequest
      // directly, since response isn't JSON format.
      $access_token_response =
        $this->_oauthRequest(
          $this->getUrl('graph', '/oauth/access_token'),
          $params = array('client_id' => $this->getAppId(),
                          'client_secret' => $this->getAppSecret(),
                          'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
                          'code' => $code));
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) { 
      // most likely that user very recently revoked authorization.
      // In any event, we don't have an access token, so say so.
      return false;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Here, the code under **catch (FacebookApiException $e)** is getting executed and hence the functioning is returning **false**. Therefore there is no access token and hence i'm unable to login i guess.

I'm a bit of a noob and don't actually know what catch (FacebookApiException $e) does. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

**EDIT:**

I tried adding **print_r($e);** like this:

```
catch (FacebookApiException $e) { 
      // most likely that user very recently revoked authorization.
      // In any event, we don't have an access token, so say so.
      print_r($e);
      return false;
}
```

and this is the error it printed out: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc7eT.png). What exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: Consider trying the new version of the SDK: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4  docs:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

Comment: @Fosco Thanks for the suggestion. I just finished trying it and the exact same thing is happening. I'm just left with the url with ?code=.... appended to it and not logged in.

Comment: You should be using a specific page for the redirect url from Facebook, and on that page, using the FacebookRedirectLoginHelper to process the code with getSessionFromRedirect.

Comment: I tried redirecting it to a different page and doing what you said. But no luck. The code from the url just isn't getting processed. I feel like the problem is with my environment because the same problem is repeating in both versions of the sdk.

Comment: @Fosco, have a look at the EDIT please.

Comment: The new SDK does not have FacebookApiException.  All code you've provided still appears to be using the old SDK.